# How to have ORDER BY recognize that the value of S is greater than A?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to order a column in the table `stats` table using `ORDER BY ASC`. I want sql to recognize S as being greater than an A. Is there some way of re-assigning values? I would like the code below to print: "S,A,A,B", so that S>A but the rest is alphabetical. New to sql and thanks.
EDIT: My apologies but I forgot to include that I attempted to organize via: `SELECT rarity FROM stats ORDER BY rarity ASC;`

```sql
CREATE TABLE stats (
    _name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    refreshingness INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    flavor INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    chuggability INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    rarity VARCHAR(1)CHARACTER SET LATIN1 NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (_name)
);
```

```sql
SELECT rarity FROM stats
ORDER BY rarity ASC;

INSERT INTO stats(_name,refreshingness,flavor,chuggability,rarity)
VALUES("Southern Style Sweet Tea",2,3,3,"S");

INSERT INTO stats(_name,refreshingness,flavor,chuggability,rarity)
VALUES("Raspberry",4,3,4,"A");

INSERT INTO stats(_name,refreshingness,flavor,chuggability,rarity)
VALUES("Iced Tea with Gingseng Zero",4,3,4,"A");

INSERT INTO stats(_name,refreshingness,flavor,chuggability,rarity)
VALUES("Half & Half Pink Tea Lemonade",2,2,2,"B");
```

Comment: And what order do you want?

Comment: I would like to have it display it as: "S, A, A, B". It begins with S and then the remainder of the list is alphabetical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand.  `'S'` > `'A'` -- in any reasonable encoding of the alphabet.  Assuming you mean the value for `rarity`, this does what you *say*:

```
order by rarity desc
```

`'S'` should be first.  Let me make a leap, and assume you want an *ascending* sort with `'S'` first.  In that case:

```
order by (rarity = 'S') desc,   -- put 'S' first
         rarity asc
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's your query. you can use `case` on your `order by` number, since number always comes first.

```
SELECT * FROM stats ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN rarity = 'S' THEN 1 
    ELSE rarity END
```

See [dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/#&togetherjs=Bas6FfqfPN)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that `rarity` is your custom ranking system where `S` is rarer than `A`, itself rarer than `B`, etc.

You can achieve the sorting you want by using the [`FIELD()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field) function of MySQL.

This query:

```
SELECT * FROM stats ORDER BY FIELD(rarity,'S','A','B')
```

would return:

```
| Southern Style Sweet Tea      | 2 | 3 | 3 | S |
| Iced Tea with Gingseng Zero   | 4 | 3 | 4 | A |
| Raspberry                     | 4 | 3 | 4 | A |
| Half & Half Pink Tea Lemonade | 2 | 2 | 2 | B |
```

Comment: What if A,B,C .. to Z?

Comment: I agree it is not a scalable solution if you are using a lot of letters. I consider it to be a reasonable solution if it is limited to a small selection like in the original question.